# Hide side bar when clic on any link <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a burger buttom. Its working perfectly but I need to add someting else on Javascript, the thing is that Im kinda new and i've no idea about javascript. I was wondering if you can help me.

I need that **when I clic on any a element, the menu gets closed** and the X turns back into a normal burg

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.burger');
const navbar = document.querySelector('nav');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

menuIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbar.classList.toggle('change');

});
menuIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('change');

});
menuIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    body.classList.toggle('change');

});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
  width:100%;
}
.change{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
header{
  height: 15vh;
  background-color:#000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 100;
  top:0;
}
header nav{
  transition: 0.4s;
}
header p{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#dfe6e9;
  padding:20px 40px;
}

header .burger{
  position:absolute;
  right:2%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
header .burger div{
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: #fff;

}
header nav ul{
  margin-top:50px;

}
.change{
  right:0;
}
.change .line1{
 transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
  background-color: #d63031;
}
.change .line2{
 opacity: 0;
}
.change .line3{
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
  background-color: #d63031;
}
header nav ul li{
  display:block;
  margin: 0px 16px;
  padding:30px 0px 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav ul li a{
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  padding:10px 5px;
  color:#fff;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  transition:.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover{
  color: #d63031;
  /* background-color:#dfe6e9; */
  /* border-radius: 20px; */
  /* padding:10px 15px; */
}
header .burger{
  width:22px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right:0%;
  padding: 0px 15px 1px 9px;
}
header .burger .line2, .line3{
  margin-top: 4px;
}
header .burger .line1, .line2, .line3{
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.part1{
  background: url(valentins2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 101%;
  background-position: center;
}
h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ff7675;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0px 0px 30px 0px;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.box1 p{
  font-size:16px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
  width:90%;
}
.box1 .buttn{
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.box1 .buttn a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  background-color: #ff7675;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight:700;
  transition:.4s;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.box1 .buttn a:hover{
  background-color: #dfe6e9;
  font-weight: 900px;
  color:#d63031;
}

.box2, .box4{
  width:100%;
  height:105vh;
  background-color:#222326;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.delineador{
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  width:85px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:31%;
}
#third{
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
}

h2{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 29px;
  font-weight:800;
  width:90%;
  font-family:"Montserrat";
  color: #fff;
  transition: .4s;
  position: absolute;
  top:7%;
}
.box2 p, .box3 p{
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  width:90%;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.box2 a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:12%;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #636e72;
}

.box2 i{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right:87%;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color:#636e72;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.box2 i:hover, a:hover{
  color:#fab1a0;
}
.box3{
  width:100%;
  height:70vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.part2{
  background: url(valentins33.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:auto 101%;
  background-position: center;
}
.mail{
  position: absolute;
  top:52%;
}
.mail a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#ff7675;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mail a:hover{
  color:#fab1a0;
}
.icon-group{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:19%;

}
.icon-group a{
  font-size: 26px;
  background-color: #636e72;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.icon-group a:hover{
  color:#fab1a0;
}
#ig{
  padding:10px 12px;
}
#fb{
  padding:10px 15px;
}
#tw{
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin:0px 35px;
}
footer{
  width:100%;
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: #636e72;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
footer p{
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1023px){
  header{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  header nav{
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    right: 2%;
    background-color: none;
  }
  header nav ul li{
  display:inline;
  margin: 0px 14px;
}
  header nav ul{
    margin-top:0;
  }
header nav ul li a{
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding:10px 0px;
  color:#dfe6e9;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  transition:.4s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  header nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #d63031;
    /* background-color:#dfe6e9; */
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* padding:10px 15px; */
  }
  header .burger{
    display:none;
  }
  h1{
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 55px;
    padding-top:114px;
  }
  .box1 p{
    width:38%;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0px 40px;
  }
  .box1 .buttn{
    margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 40px 40px 40px;
  }

  .box2,.box4{
    height: 70vh;
  }
  .box2 p,.box4 p{
    width:60%;
  }
  .box3 p{
    width:60%;
  }
  #third{
    top:35%;
  }
  #tw{
    margin:0px 45px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:732px){
  .part1,.part2{
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1023px){
  header nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right: -100%;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

  header{
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    height: 54px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Ballon bouquet</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600,800,900|Open+Sans:400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f7c1027ae7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <article class="part1" id="scroll1">
    <header>
      <p>Fantasy Ballons</p>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="lis" data-scroll href="#scroll1">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="lis" data-scroll href="#scroll2">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a class="lis" data-scroll href="#scroll3">About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="lis" data-scroll href="#scroll4">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </header>
      <section class="box1">
          <h1>Online Shopping</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
             sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
             ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
             ,quis nostrud exercitatiasdfasdfadfon ullamco laboris nisi </p>
        <p class="buttn"> <a href="http://www.balloonbouquet.com.mialias.net/">Buy Now</a></p>
      </section>
  </article>
  <section class="box2" id="scroll2">
    <h2>Discover our promotions</h2>
    <div class="delineador"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim </p>
    <a href="http://www.balloonbouquet.com.mialias.net/">Check out! <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </section>
  <article class="part2" id="scroll3">
    <section class="box3">
      <h2>Who are we?</h2>
      <div class="delineador"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim </p>
    </section>
  </article>
  <section class="box4" id="scroll4">
    <h2>Follow us on social networks!</h2>
    <div class="delineador" id="third"></div>
    <p class="mail"><a href="#">Fantasyballoonsmn@gmail.com</a></p>
    <div class="icon-group">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/fantasyballoonsmn/?igshid=4tjmhgygzn34&fbclid=IwAR2ery7dREwZsVODZa9hv-gv9e6aWkq6Kt8WrEci1snxH7mwHpM-YaWvLx4" title="Instagram"<i class="fab fa-instagram" id="ig"></i></a>
      <a href="#" title="Twitter"<i class="fab fa-twitter" id="tw"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fantasyballoonsmn/" title="Facebook"<i class="fab fa-facebook-f" id="fb"></i></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright © 2020 Fantasyballoonsmn</p>
  </footer>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

er, same as when you clic on the X. 
Would you tell me the code lines I need to add on my css and js files to do so? Id really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your javascript with this

```
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.burger');
const navbar = document.querySelector('nav');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.lis')

menuIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuIcon.classList.toggle('change');
  body.classList.toggle('change');
  navbar.classList.toggle('change');
});

menuLinks.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('change');
    body.classList.toggle('change');
    navbar.classList.toggle('change');
  })
});
```

Comment: BROOOOOOOOO AAAAAAAAAA I worked perfectly. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH. God bless you man, The world needs more people like you. You have no idea how happy im now hahah <3 youre amazing. One last question, is it basic or advanced Javascript what I requiered to do this?

Comment: Hey bro! Sorry for bothering you, theres another little issue:)
When the page is open on full screen, (no burger at all), and I clic on the nav links, the overflow Y dissapears at all. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks again